# is using maven with java project decrease size of war?

Tags: java, maven, size, war, web-deployment

currently we have java web project and we are not using maven. When we create war file its size is too much. I want to decrease this war file size.

I think this much war size is because of libraries (almost 50% or total).

So is that possible that if we **USE MAVEN THEN OUR WAR FILE SIZE WILL BE DECREASED.**

Comment: Just throw away useless libs.

Comment: Why the size of war file is problem for you?

Comment: Do you use "provided" scope for your container jars?

Comment: @Maksym actually we need to update war file frequently in week two -three time and the actually client server is at three four places so when internet get slow upload download take good amount of time. So if size decreased then this will be done speedily

Comment: @Maksym "provided" scope no.

Answer (score 1):

Using Maven won't necessarily decrease your WAR size.  It might help you to eliminate transitive dependent JAR files that are no longer required, but that only applies if you have such unnecessary dependencies.

Having said that, the Maven "Shade" plugin can be configured to combine multiple component JARs into a single JAR ... and eliminate classes from dependent JARs that are not actually used.  Look for the shade plugin's `minimizeJar` config parameter.

Reference:

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

---

I'm curious as to why the size of the WAR file is a concern.  The web container JVM will only load the classes that the webapp actually uses.  Other classes don't get loaded, and don't use significant amounts of JVM memory.  Sure, a bloated WAR file uses more disk space than is necessary, but disk space is cheap on a typical web server platform.

Answer (score 0):

According to the our comments conversation under the question:

- *Just throw away useless libs. –  Maksym 16 hours ago*
- *Why the size of war file is problem for you? –  Maksym 16 hours ago*
- Do you use "provided" scope for your container jars? –  Maksym 16 hours ago
- *@Maksym actually we need to update war file frequently in week two -three time and the actually client server is at three four places so when internet get slow upload download take good amount of time. So if size decreased then this will be done speedily –  murtaza.webdev 1 hour ago*
- *@Maksym "provided" scope no. –  murtaza.webdev 1 hour ago*

Solution, will bet to set up "provided" scope for the jars of container. Actually it's highly recommended to use this scope for container jars in order to have correct working webapp.

You should have dependency like this for container jars:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```